# Como abrir un jar (que lee un archivo .properties) con otro jar

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

He desarrollado un aplicación para el "Registro de Visitantes", esta aplicación se conecta a MySQL para guardar lo registros, para determinar a que base conectarse obtiene este parámetro de un archivo de Propiedades. La aplicación funciona por si sola sin problemas.

El problema surge al querer abrir esta aplicación desde otra app. Me indica que no localiza el archivo de propiedades. El código que uso para abrir el jar desde otro jar es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cmd = "java -jar C:/Users/adnk1/Desktop/AccessControl14-12-2018/AccessControlProduccion.jar";
  try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Trato de hacer esta app con la finalidad de consultar a otra base de datos si existe alguna actualización de la aplicacion de "Registro de Visitantes".

Quisiera saber si estoy omitiendo algo, porque como menciono la aplicación de "Registro de Visitantes" funciona por si sola, así que supongo que algo me esta faltando en la programación de jar que abre al otro jar. Saludos.

Comment: mi pregunta es: cual es la necesidad de abrir un .jar con otro .jar?no le allo sentido? me lo puedes explicar la razon?

Comment: Hola simon, lo que quiero es desarrollar una app que consulte en base de datos si existe una actualización de la app de Registro de visitantes, si la hay, la descargará, la descomprimira del zip, y la sustituirá una vez remplazados los archivos fuente.

Comment: ah okay ya te entiendo, intentas hacer algo como un update de version de  la App?

Comment: Básicamente, para darle soporte a la app, por si se llegase a pedir mejoras en la app principal (la de registro de visitantes) y asi no tener que ir equipo por equipo a actualizar los archivos fuente.

Comment: bueno yo lo haria mas sencillo mira: crearia un boton donde dija "ultima version o  "actualizar software" algo asi y dentro del metodo de ese boton crear un objecto que cree una llamada a una base de datos exerna (en un servidor free o pago donde encuentre almacenada la posible nueva version) y cuando se realize una  peticion por un archivo llamado por ejemplo "vernew" o algo asi si sale que no exista pues muestra un mensaje que no hay nueva version y asi vicerversa y para remplazar sencillamente usaria un metodo en java que elimine los archivos desde la raiz,bueno yo crearia eso esta manera.

Comment: asi es simon, ya solo me falta realizar la app secundaria o la que se encargue del update; pero al intentar abrir la app principal me tira error, indicando que no encuentra el archivo de propiedades, pero este si se encuentra en la ruta donde se va a buscar. Y quiero pensar que algo me esta faltando indicar en la app del Update.

Comment: según yo, no se puede auto-editar o eliminar el jar mientras esta en ejecución, por eso es que voy por depender de la app que se encargue del Update. ya que si hay nueva actualización hare que borre la app actual y sustituya por la nueva.

Comment: si se puede pero mala practica y quiza java te muestre un error de alerta pero si se puede,podrias crear un boton que descarge un .step y el usuario lo instale por si mismo o si lo quieres mas cool podrias crear un intalador https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_uK_IhKbfAhVKeawKHQBYASwQwqsBMAB6BAgCEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXITTQGD8V1s&usg=AOvVaw20u7xPoX13EIzaCEcAOM6R  y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685149/creating-an-installer-for-java-desktop-application

Comment: y desde ahi mimo puedes intalarlo y que se cierre la app y se instale el software pero sin toca ni mover tu BD y asi solo se update tu software y no tu registro de visitantes

Comment: mientras leeo tu codigo: aqui     String cmd = "java -jar C:/Users/adnk1/Desktop/AccessControl14-12-2018/AccessControlProduccion.jar"; estas seguro que tu ruta esta bien? mientra leeo el codigo lo  veo bien

Comment: checaré los links que adjuntas, y si, la ubicación es correcta ya que inicia la app con un splash y al cargar los componentes y al intentar realizar la conexión arroja el error de que no encuentra el archivo de propiedades el cual le pasa el dato de a que base realizar la conexión.

Comment: revise los enlaces, y si recuerdo que ya había intentado realizar un exe a partir del jar y a pesar de que seguí los pasos no funcionaba, asi que decidí dejarlo de lado, ademas de que solo funcionarían en Windows y si no me equivoco el jar de puede ejecutar desde cualquier SO, siempre y cuando tenga instalado Java. La verdad no se si me equivoco, soy nuevo en esta aventura de programar en Java

Comment: mira esto te va a servir mucho (solo si sabes ingles) https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190944-creating-an-updater-in-java/ y aqui me encontre con la mima pregunta en ingles